Python3 Flask app: How to create multiple log files that each log there own information
I am trying to create multiple log files what can be used throughout a Flask app to log various types of information including, battery data, login data, system data, etc.
So I was able to create a single log file the currently hold all of my logging info.
It is initialized in main.py to log the startup information of the app to the console.
# Main.py

from app import create_app
import os
import logging
import subprocess
import uuid


app = create_app()

# Initialize logging
logging.basicConfig(
    level=app.config.LOG_LVL,
    format="[%(asctime)s]: {} %(levelname)s %(message)s".format(os.getpid()),
    datefmt="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
)
logger = logging.getLogger()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host=app.config.API_ADDR,
            port=app.config.API_PORT,
            debug=app.config.DEBUG,
            use_reloader=app.config.RELOADER
            )


Later in app/__init__.py, the basic config is tweaked with a file location:
# __init__.py


logger = logging.getLogger()

def create_app():
  app = Flask(__name__)
  logger.info("Initializing App")
  # Initialize Plugins
  FlaskDynaconf(
      app,
      SETTINGS_FILE="settings.yaml",
  )

 # Initialize logging
  os.makedirs(app.config["LOG_DIRECTORY"], exist_ok=True)
  logging.basicConfig(
      filename=f"{app.config['LOG_DIRECTORY']}/{app.config['LOG_FILENAME']}",
      level=app.config.LOG_LVL,
      format="[%(asctime)s]: {} %(levelname)s %(message)s".format(
          os.getpid()),
      datefmt="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",
      filemode="a",
  )


Given that the scope of the project is getting larger, I want to have certain function log to different files to clean up the primary log file. For Example, I want all battery logging to go to a battery.log and all login logging to go towards login.log.
I am having trouble creating multiple loggers to handle all of the different types of logs I am trying to manage.

Instead of using basicConfig() you have to attach multiple Handlers to the root logger manually.
